# Multiple #ifndef vs. single one #endif

Tags: library, tcpip, modbus

My question is connected with the issue as linked:
[Is there any good working MODBUS TCP master library available for Arduino?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/36234/is-there-any-good-working-modbus-tcp-master-library-available-for-arduino)

An example of Modbus TCP master library as suggested in the post above. A part of ModbusTCP.h file:

```
#ifndef Modbus_TCPIP_h
#define Modbus_TCPIP_h

#ifndef WIZNET_W5100
#define WIZNET_W5100  0       /**< define 1 if  WIZNET W5100 IC is used, otherwise 0 */
#ifndef ENC28J60
#define ENC28J60      1       /**< define 1 if  ENC28J60 IC is used, otherwise 0     */
#ifndef ESP8266
#define ESP8266       0

//...The entire code of the header

#endif // Just a single one occurence of the #endif in the last line of the header code! 8-|
```

When I've run the compilation of it in my Arduino IDE, I've got an error as follows: unterminated #ifndef. Mentioned error has a four ocurrences in the error log and it is linked to: Modbus_TCPIP_h, WIZNET_W5100 and ENC28J60.

What should be modified in the header file?

Comment: These of course each need to be matched by an ending, as they are fully independent.  Are you confusing this with else clauses?

Comment: It's a bug in the library. Someone submitted a PR: https://github.com/goddland16/Modbus-TCP/pull/2 and the library owner merged it. Apparently neither of them bothered to test the code or even give it a quick look. That doesn't give me much confidence in the quality of their work. My advice is to look for an alternative library of higher quality.

Comment: you might have figured it out yourself if you asked `why is ESP8266 not getting an error`

Comment: Dear All. As per per1234 suggestion I would place the main question ones again: Is there any good working and also tested and proven MODBUS TCP master library available for Arduino?

Answer (score 0):

The code is missing "#endif". Should look something like this:

```
#ifndef WIZNET_W5100
#define WIZNET_W5100  0       /**< define 1 if  WIZNET W5100 IC is used, otherwise 0 */
#endif
#ifndef ENC28J60
#define ENC28J60      1       /**< define 1 if  ENC28J60 IC is used, otherwise 0     */
#endif
#ifndef ESP8266
#define ESP8266       0
#endif
```

Cheers!

Comment: A new error available:modbusTCPlib_enc28j60:23: error: token "=" is not valid in preprocessor expressions

 #define ENC28J60     = 1

Comment: Did you accept the answer above? And now adding a new question. Fun!

Comment: I'm trying fix the bugs in the code. In the moment nothing works. All trails brings nothing. So I would ask ones again. Is there any good working and also tested and proven and error free MODBUS TCP master library available for Arduino? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you read how to use this site? https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tour I recommend that you follow this procedure. It will give you more answers and friends.